# Symfony, Doctrine - Create database column from frontend

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity

I am fairly new to web dev and symfony. Right now I have two separate projects (frontend/backend). The frontend with angular/ionic and the backend with symfony/doctrine. I have a database with the entity 'product'. And for that product I have created the column 'name'. I managed to do that by adding the appropriate lines in the diffrent files in the backend. For example: src/Entity/product.php

What I like to do is that I have in the connected frontend code a textfield and a send button. You enter for example 'manufacturer' in the textfield and it automatically adds a column to the product entity with that name. (min/max length and if its requiered does not matter for now I think).

I did a lot of reading about symfony/doctrine but I does not seem to be possible as I imagined it.

Sorry for not posting any code attempts, but I wouldn't even know where to start with that kind of task. I think the problem is more structural/conceptual. Maybe I have to create a collections column in my entity and fill that collection with all the new columns that I want as a string or something like that.

I am thankful for any kind of advices. And sorry again, for my probably awful post.

Kind regards

Comment: Changing your schema on the fly is not easily possible and potentially risky. You could use a document database or use a json field in mysql to store the dynamically changing data. A JSON field is harder to query, so you should keep that in mind.

Comment: so you could inject the field into the entity. Then run php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff; php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --no-interaction;

Comment: @RobertSaylor Do you have a link where I can read about the injection part? I am still unsure about many things. For example do I have to transfer the name and properties of the column to the backend somehow first? And the backend lets doctrine handle the rest or something like that?